# Select WHERE @where = @term returning an empty row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone explain to me where I'm going wrong with this query? Inserting the parameters into the `@where` and `@term` causes it to work fine but within the context of my asp.net application where the parameters are required it falls over.

I have a profiler watching the server and this is what is happening when the interface that activates this query is used:

```
exec sp_executesql N' 
    SELECT 
        CC,  simNumber,  Voice,  IMSI,  Network,  SOA,  
        Customer, Description,  partNumber,  serialNumber,  Contract,  issueDate,  
        expiryDate,  Datagate, status,  originalSheet,  originalRow  
    FROM tblViews  
    WHERE @where = @term ',N'@where nvarchar(3),@term nvarchar(5)',@where=N'SOA',
        @term=N'64367'
go
```

Am I Missing something? I can't really see any Issue as to why this wouldn't work. Is there a rule that you can't specify what to search for and in which column in the same query?

Comment: beware of sql injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is syntactically malformed, more specifically:

```
WHERE @where = @term
--    ^^^^^^
--   this bit
```

Variables (such as `@where` and `@term`) can only contain values (therefore your particular use of `@term` is correct), but not table names, column names, SQL syntax, etc. (therefore your particular use of `@where` is incorrect).

Search Google or Stack Overflow for "**Dynamic SQL**", which is the name for what you're trying to do. One resource that I recommend for SQL Server is [Erland Sommarskog's article, "Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL"](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

There are various pitfalls with Dynamic SQL. One that deserves special mention is the possibility of a type of security issue, so-called [**SQL injection attacks**](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection). Therefore, make sure to check out [the section that shows how to combine dynamic SQL query text and variables](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#sp_executesql) without introducing that security issue.

Comment: Yeah I tried the same query removing the where and leaving the desired column. All worked fine. Thanks for the Starting point @stakx I'll do a bit of reading now.

Comment: @Tinydan: I've expanded my answer and added links to two articles by an expert on the topic of Dynamic SQL. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've decided to do as the the article suggests and not pass the where clause to a stored procedure. I have an if statement that looks at the users selection and bases the query from that. I may change to have multiple stored procedures for each selection and then have the applications elect which procedure to use but for now this will work.